# Using admob again in the application that received the warning "Ad serving is limited"

Tags: react-native, admob

I started getting a warning saying "Ad serving is limited" in my React Native app and ads are no longer showing. I also use my app on PlayStore and naturally I can see my own ads. When I researched, I found out that this is prohibited and I never thought it would be illegal. I don't want to work with any other ad service other than Admob. I have two questions regarding this situation:

1- Is it okay if I open a new admob account and put ads in the same application again and add my own device as a test device this time? I mean, don't I have the right to do something like this because this practice was penalized before?

2- Where can I find a list of such strict rules in order not to experience a similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not problem if you only opening the app to see the ads, but it's forbidden to click the ads.
It's not allowed to have 2 admob account per user, once it found out, your both admob can be banned permanently.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9686306?hl=en

Check again how you serve your ads, I have limited ads before, then I found what the reason and update the apps, limit got removed within one week.

Comment: I didn't know I had to add test device but I added it. I show 1 ad after the user writes a message to a field 3 times. Do you think this will cause a problem?

Comment: the problem with my ads is inside the list it's showing after 5 data, so it's dynamic depends on data, the request went very high and I got the limit, I think the ads should be natural, cannot be dynamic depend like data for my case, once I remove it, limit is gone till now, no more limit